# SELECT в хранимых функциях

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть обычная функция:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ISFUNC(ID IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN

    IF (ID = 2 OR ID = 5) THEN
    RETURN('TRUE');
    ELSE 
    RETURN('FALSE');
    END IF;

END ISFUNC;
/
```

Суть ее вроде бы понятна. Как в нее можно вставить SELECT? Т.е. чтобы в IF были не конкретные числа, а результат селекта?
Пусть, например, есть такой SELECT:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM Table
```

Результатом этого селекта являются две строки: 2 и 5.

Как правильно вставить этот SELECT в функцию? Пытался в сам IF, но понял, что не правильно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ISFUNC(ID IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS
    l_exst number;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) 
    INTO l_exst
    FROM Table t 
    WHERE t.id = ID;

    IF (l_exst <> 0) THEN
        RETURN('TRUE');
    ELSE 
        RETURN('FALSE');
    END IF;
END ISFUNC;
/
```

или

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ISFUNC(ID IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS
BEGIN
    FOR x IN ( SELECT ID FROM Table )
    LOOP
        IF (ID = x.ID) THEN
            RETURN('TRUE');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN('FALSE');
END ISFUNC;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант решения данной задачи:

```
SQL> create table tab(id number);
Table created

SQL> insert into tab values (2);
1 row inserted

SQL> insert into tab values (5);
1 row inserted

SQL> select * from tab;
        ID
----------
         2
         5

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ISFUNC(pID IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
  2  IS
  3    result varchar2(5);
  4  BEGIN
  5      select decode(count(*),0,'FALSE','TRUE') into result
  6        from tab
  7       where tab.id=pid;
  8      return(result);
  9  END ISFUNC;
 10  /

SQL> select level, isfunc(level) from dual connect by level<=10;
     LEVEL ISFUNC(LEVEL)
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 FALSE
         2 TRUE
         3 FALSE
         4 FALSE
         5 TRUE
         6 FALSE
         7 FALSE
         8 FALSE
         9 FALSE
        10 FALSE
10 rows selected
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно объявить переменную `@count` и выполнить запрос:

```
select @count = count(*) from Table where id in (2, 5)
```

А затем проверить количество строк:

```
if (@count > 0)
```

P.S. Синтаксиса PL/SQL уже не помню, но неточности подправите сами, если что.